Biconjugate of a nonconvex function and global minimum
Since the convex biconjugate of a function is the largest convex function bellow it, I assume that the minimum of the biconjugate function is the same as the global minimum of the original function in the case the original global minimum was unique (no matter whether the original function was convex or not). I assume that the function is continuous and proper.
I have a non convex function F(x) = f(x) + g(x), where f(x) is non convex and g(x) is convex. F(x) has a unique global minimum, but the global minima of f and g separated are not unique. Is the global minimum of F** (or F) same as the global minimum of f**(x) + g(x)? Both f and g are continuous, proper functions whose minima are 0.

Honestly, I do not understand the down/close votes. There is enough context in the question. Not understanding the notation $\ne$ not enough context.

Not true. Take
$$ 
f(x) = \min( |x+1|, 1), \quad g(x) = (x-1)^2.
$$
Then $f\ge0$, $g\ge0$, $f(-1)=0$, $g(+1)=0$, $f^{**} = 0$. The minimum of $f^{**}+g$ is zero. The global minimum of $f+g$ is $\min_x f(x)+g(x) =1$.
Then $F^{**}(x) \ge 1$, which implies
$$
\min_x f^{**}(x) + g(x) < \min_x F^{**}(x).
$$
Since $f^{**}+g$ is a convex function below $f+g$, we directly have the inequality
$$
f^{**}+g \le F^{**}.
$$
